# Zend Framework: How do I change the default layout script to something other than layout.phtml?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'd like to name my default layout file something other than layout.phtml, since it doesn't really describe what type of layout it is.  How can I do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your Bootstrap.php file, you could do something like this:

```
protected function _initLayoutName()
{
    // use sitelayout.phtml as the main layout file
    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('sitelayout');
}
```

If you want to use a different layout for a different module, you need to register a plugin in the Bootstrap and have the plugin contain the following code:

```
class Application_Plugin_LayoutSwitcher extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $module = $request->getModuleName(); // get the name of the current module

        if ('admin' == $module) {
            // set the layout to admin.phtml if we are in admin module
            Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('admin');
        } else if ('somethingelse' == $module) {
            Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('somethingelse');
        }
    }
}
```

From within your application.ini, you can do this to set the layout script:

```
resources.layout.layout = "layoutname"
```

This will not work on a per layout basis, however.  If you need to change the layout based on the module, you will have to use a plugin, but you can use the setting in application.ini to set the default layout name.

Comment: thx!  This is what I was looking for, but is there any way to do it in the ini config file?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a specific layout depending on based on your modules 
you can create a plugin and register it in your boostrap :

```
<?php

class Plugin_LayoutModule extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
{
        /**
         * preDispatch function.
         * 
         * Define layout path based on what module is being used.
         */
        public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
        {
                $module = strtolower($request->getModuleName());
                $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();

                if ($layout->getMvcEnabled())
                {
                        $layout->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/' . $module . '/layouts/');
                        $layout->setLayout($module);
                }
        }
}

//Register it in your bootstrap.php     
    <?php
        defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
            or define('APPLICATION_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
        ...

        Zend_Layout::startMvc();
        $frontController->registerPlugin(new Plugin_LayoutModule()); 
    ?>
```

**EDIT :**

to set your layout to another file using .ini file :

create `layout.ini` file and put in it :

```
[layout]
layout = "foo"
layoutPath = "/path/to/layouts"
contentKey = "CONTENT"
```

in your bootstrap file :

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/layout.ini', 'layout');

$layout = Zend_Layout::startMvc($config);
```

Comment: Thx for the help!  As I asked drew010 earlier, is there any way to set the default layout name through the ini config file?